# Security firewall uses wrong provider

Tags: symfony5

I use Symfony 5.3 and this is my security.yaml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/experimental_authenticators.html
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
        app_project_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Project
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_profiler|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        api_doc:
            pattern: ^/api/doc
            security: false
        api:
            pattern: ^/api/
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\ApiKeyAuthenticator
            provider: app_project_provider
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            entry_point: form_login
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api/, roles: [ ROLE_PROJECT ] }
        - { path: ^/, roles: [ ROLE_ADMIN ] }
```

But I notised that it uses always the first mentioned provider (for this example it uses app_project_provider for 'api' and 'main' firewalls).

I've tried to use different routes and write my own user providers, it always work this way.

Maybe someone knows what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have is to chain provider fro both firewalls:

```
security:
    password_hashers:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
        app_project_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Project
        all_providers:
            chain:
                providers: [app_user_provider, app_project_provider]
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_profiler|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        api_doc:
            pattern: ^/api/doc
            security: false
        api:
            pattern: ^/api/
            lazy: true
            stateless: true
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\ApiKeyAuthenticator
            provider: all_providers
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: all_providers
            entry_point: form_login
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api/, roles: [ ROLE_PROJECT ] }
        - { path: ^/, roles: [ ROLE_USER ] }
```